# Error when returning from a second Activity to MainActivity in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am in a second activity and within this function I want to return to the MainActivity taking two variables using intent, but it gives me an error, how can I correct this

```
    private void connectToWifi(final String wifiSSID) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.config_issd);

    dialog.setTitle("Connect to Network");

    mISSD = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_issd);
    mButtonAceptar = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_aceptar);
    mPassword = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    mISSD.setText(wifiSSID);

    mButtonAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String NewPassword = mPassword.getText().toString();
            String NewISSD = mISSD.getText().toString();

ERROR??     Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext().MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("myISSD",NewISSD);
            myIntent.putExtra("myPassword",NewPassword);
            startActivity(myIntent);

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Typo: `view.getContext().MainActivity.class` should be `view.getContext(), MainActivity.class` - note the comma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your Intent as the following :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(secondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("myISSD",NewISSD);
        myIntent.putExtra("myPassword",NewPassword);
        startActivity(myIntent);
```